# Debugging ADF and Databrickswith display dataframes

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have ADF pipelines that calls Azure Databricks notebook. I want to call an ADF pipeline in normal mode(high performance) and then in debug mode.

When in debug mode, I want to display some DFs(Data frames) in databricks. But when run normally DFs should not displayed.

To achieve this I am thinking of sending parameters from ADF (debug=true) and let the display happen in an 'if' condition in databricks notebook. Is this the recommended approach or are there builtin functionlities in databricks or ADF?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the ask ,you are trying to to capture if the pipeline was initiated in debug mode or scheduled trigger mode . I think you can use the expression

`@pipeline().TriggerName` .

Atleast when I tested for debug mode it shows the value as "Sanbox" or for scheduled mode you its shows the trigger name which triggered the pipeline .

You can pass this as a parameter to the notebook and put a IF statement to add your logic .

HTH